# Jersey Client Connection Closed

Tags: java, jersey, dropwizard

Getting an error due to the client closing a connection to my dropwizard service.

The issue is that the connection is getting closed and when jersey tries to flush to this connection, it has obviously been closed so this is impossible. The problem is that this is getting returned as an IOException which is cluttering my logging. Ideally I don't care if the client is closing the connection, but there is no way for me to suppress this since it is getting fired during the `WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed`.

Ideally I want some configuration from Jersey to not throw an error when the client has closed the connection.

Error:

```
ERROR [2018-11-06 21:42:07,918] org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder: An I/O error has occurred while writing a response message entity to the container output stream.
! java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
! at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.writev0(Native Method)
! at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.writev(SocketDispatcher.java:51)
! at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:148)
! at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:504)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint.flush(ChannelEndPoint.java:179)
! ... 75 common frames omitted
! Causing: org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException: null
! at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint.flush(ChannelEndPoint.java:199)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.io.WriteFlusher.flush(WriteFlusher.java:420)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.io.WriteFlusher.write(WriteFlusher.java:313)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractEndPoint.write(AbstractEndPoint.java:147)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection$SendCallback.process(HttpConnection.java:739)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.util.IteratingCallback.processing(IteratingCallback.java:241)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.util.IteratingCallback.iterate(IteratingCallback.java:224)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.send(HttpConnection.java:519)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.sendResponse(HttpChannel.java:737)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.write(HttpChannel.java:788)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.gzip.GzipHttpOutputInterceptor.write(GzipHttpOutputInterceptor.java:108)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.write(HttpOutput.java:235)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.write(HttpOutput.java:219)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.write(HttpOutput.java:491)
! at java.io.OutputStream.write(OutputStream.java:75)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.internal.ResponseWriter$NonCloseableOutputStreamWrapper.write(ResponseWriter.java:320)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.CommittingOutputStream.write(CommittingOutputStream.java:218)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$UnCloseableOutputStream.write(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:294)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ByteArrayProvider.writeTo(ByteArrayProvider.java:96)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ByteArrayProvider.writeTo(ByteArrayProvider.java:60)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor.invokeWriteTo(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:265)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:250)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:162)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.JsonWithPaddingInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(JsonWithPaddingInterceptor.java:106)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:162)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.java:86)
! ... 50 common frames omitted
! Causing: org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.process.MappableException: org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException
! at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.java:92)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:162)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyFactory.writeTo(MessageBodyFactory.java:1130)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.writeResponse(ServerRuntime.java:711)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.processResponse(ServerRuntime.java:444)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.process(ServerRuntime.java:434)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:329)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:305)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1154)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:473)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:427)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:388)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:341)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:228)
! at io.dropwizard.jetty.NonblockingServletHolder.handle(NonblockingServletHolder.java:49)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1772)
! at io.dropwizard.servlets.ThreadNameFilter.doFilter(ThreadNameFilter.java:34)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1759)
! at io.dropwizard.jersey.filter.AllowedMethodsFilter.handle(AllowedMethodsFilter.java:50)
! at io.dropwizard.jersey.filter.AllowedMethodsFilter.doFilter(AllowedMethodsFilter.java:44)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1759)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:582)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1180)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:512)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1112)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)
! at com.codahale.metrics.jetty9.InstrumentedHandler.handle(InstrumentedHandler.java:240)
! at io.dropwizard.jetty.ContextRoutingHandler.handle(ContextRoutingHandler.java:38)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.gzip.GzipHandler.handle(GzipHandler.java:493)
! at io.dropwizard.jetty.BiDiGzipHandler.handle(BiDiGzipHandler.java:68)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.StatisticsHandler.handle(StatisticsHandler.java:169)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:534)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:320)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:251)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:283)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:108)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:93)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.executeProduceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:303)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:148)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:136)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:671)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:589)
! at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: I don't have a fix for this, but I believe this is related to Jersey issue 3412: https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jersey/issues/3412